# ssh-copy-id Permission Denied AND ansible all -m ping Unreachable

Tags: ansible, redhat, ansible-inventory, ssh-keygen

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-93-205 ~]$ ssh-copy-id 172.31.81.164
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
ansible@172.31.81.164's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
ansible@172.31.81.164's password:
```

---

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-93-205 ~]$ ansible all -m ping
172.31.81.164 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansible@172.31.81.164: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I changed PasswordAuthentication NO to YES, but still doesn't work

Comment: Are you definitely using the correct password?

Comment: Try `ssh ansible@172.31.81.164` first to check, whether you have the right credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ssh-copy-id and also specify the user on which you copy the credentials. `ssh-copy-id ansible@172.31.81.164`

If the ansible user does not exist on the destination machine, it should be created.

Comment: thanks, after adding user , my script works!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error

```
fatal ... UNREACHABLE! => ... Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ... Permission denied ... "unreachable": true}
```

when trying to run an ansible playbook from CentOS (control node) on a docker container (managed node) to test playbooks locally.

Make sure there is `authorized_keys` file in a default `.ssh` directory on a managed node. ssh as your user into managed node and check file is there, create it if not there

```
cd ~/.ssh
touch authorized_keys
```

On control node (where ansible is installed)

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub myuse@managed_node_ip
```

Now `authorized_keys` on a managed node should have your `id_rsa.pub` key. Try to run a playbook from control node.